# Which is the best way to inject a repository class into ViewModel?

Tags: android, kotlin, repository, viewmodel, dagger-2

I'm curious which method is better

```
class CustomViewModel @Inject constructor(private val repo: CustomRepository) : ViewModel()
```

or this

```
class CustomViewModel @Inject constructor() : ViewModel() {
     @Inject
     lateinit var repo: CustomRepository
}
```

Comment: It depends. For example, do you want to unit test your viewmodel? If yes, how would you mock `CustomRepository` with the second approach?

Comment: Definitely the first one. The second one would effectively make the CustoMViewModel not testeable

Comment: So in case of testing the best solution would be first option. Thanks you!

Comment: I'd always opt for the first variant (constructor injection) if I had the choice. Sometimes you don't have a choice, e.g. when you need an empty constructor (activity). http://dillonbuchanan.com/programming/dependency-injection-constructor-vs-property/

Answer (score 0):

According to Android documentation: [Field injection should only be used in Android framework classes where constructor injection cannot be used.](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/dagger-android#dagger-in-android)

The reason is that when you inject, you need to use a graph, and to use the graph, you typically need an instance of an application class.

```
class MyApplication: Application() {
    // Reference to the application graph that is used across the whole app
    val appComponent = DaggerApplicationComponent.create()
}
```

and whenever you need to inject:

```
fun inject() {
    (applicationContext as MyApplication).appComponent.inject(this)
}
```

Thus, if you inject in your ViewModel, it becomes essentially untestable because you will need to replace the application class with a mock or a fake, which is difficult or impossible to do.

Therefore, I advise you to inject whatever you need into your Activity or Fragment class and then pass these variables as parameters to the ViewModelFactory that you will need to isntantiate your ViewModel. You can read more about it [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel/viewmodel-factories).